# Get column collection or charset type ( latin1_swedish_ci or utf8_general_ci )

Tags: php, mysql

**How to get column information with charset type.**

**Like :** utf8_general_ci , latin1_swedish_ci , latin1_german1_ci , latin1_spanish_ci , utf8_german2_ci

**I have tried :**

**1.** DESC table_name

**2.** DESCRIBE table_name

**3.** SHOW COLUMNS FROM table_name

**4.** EXPLAIN table_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the information from `information_schema`.`COLUMNS` or using `SHOW CREATE TABLE name`